# What does this sentence mean "It is NP-hard to approximate the Max-3-DM with bound 2 "?

Tags: complexity-theory, approximation, np-complete

It has been shown that: it is NP-hard to approximate the maximum 3-dimensional matching problem (Max-3-DM) to within 95/94, this result apply to instances with exactly two occurrences of each element.

Does this mean that, the Max-3-DM with the bound 2 on the number of occurrences of each element in triples, is NP-hard?

I have found a polynomial reduction from the Max-3-DM with bound 2 to my problem, can I say that my problem is NP-hard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is indeed NP-hard to approximate MAX-3DM with exactly two instances of each element within 95/94, then it's NP-hard to solve MAX-3DM with exactly two instances of each element. Specifically, if you could solve the problem exactly, then you could end up with an approximation better than 95/94 of the optimal solution (namely, you'd have something that was exactly accurate).

Generally speaking, if it's NP-hard to approximate a problem to within a factor of 1+ε, it's NP-hard to solve it exactly because an exact solution is essentially a 1-approximation of the true answer.

Comment: it is exactely what I am searching for,  I would like just to confirm the following: I have found a polynomial reduction from  the Max-3-DM with exactly two instances of each element to my problem, can I say that my problem is NP-hard?

Comment: I believe so, assuming you're right about the hardness of approximation result.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, this sentence means that the approximation problem is *NP-hard*. It says nothing about Max-3-DM problem itself.

Regardless of that, in order to prove that Your problem is *NP-hard*, You have to reduce some *NP-complete* problem to Your problem. So even if Max-3-DM is *NP-hard*, reduction to Max-3-DM problem is not enough. You would have to reduce Max-3-DM to Your problem (that is, in the opposite direction) and Max-3-DM would have to be *NP-complete*.

Comment: In fact I have reduced Max 3-DM with the bound 2 on the number of occurrences of each element in triples to my problem, I mad a mistak in my question. And I would like to know if this is sufficient to say that my problem is NP-hard. I have found that the Max 3-DM with bound bigger than or equal to 3 is NP-hard. But for bound 2 I have found that it is NP-hard to approximate this problem to within 95/94. So what do you think?

Comment: Well the problem is whether Max-3-DM is NP-complete because NP-hard is not enough. I have found this [paper](ftp://ftp1.nada.kth.se/Theory/Viggo-Kann/max3dm.pdf), which says its MaxSNP-complete. I don't know yet if MaxSNP-complete problems are NP-complete though.

Comment: Yes I have read this paper, the complete version can be found [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002001909190246E) . I think it is sufficient to say that Max-3-DM is NP-hard (I read some papers that used the Max-3-DM with bound 3). But my problem is in the bound, in this paper they proved that Max-3-DM is MaxSNP-complete for bound bigger than or equal to 3. But I have used in my reduction bound equal to 2.